# fatal: unable to exec /etc/s6/current/scripts/rc.init: no such file or directory

Tags: arch-linux, boot, pacman, artix-linux

During the update, my computer turned off. After the reboot, I tried to restore the download of pacman packages (pacman successfully updated everything). I reboot my computer but it couldn't boot. I am using artix linux with s6 init system.

[image: Boot error]